# Digital image - softening egdes

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, image-manipulation

I have some pictures that, after cutting background, have sharp edges. I would like to soften them.

What is the best way to do this with c# ?

Can you recommend me some algorithms or libraries?

Thanks in advance,

nella

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Soft edged images in GDI+](http://danbystrom.se/2008/08/24/soft-edged-images-in-gdi/).